# Comparing 2 variables in SSIS

Tags: ssis

As part of an ETL process that already exists, I'm having to add a validation check.
This involves comparing the record count of a CSV file to the Metadata accompanying it.

The metadata has already been stored in the DB at this point and I've managed to get it by adding an Execute SQL block and storing the output to a variable. 
Once the file is read, as part of a Data flow task [as designed in the SSIS package already], I capture the rowcount from this using a Row Count transformation block in the Data Flow.

I need to compare these values and if not equal, fail.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

What I've tried so far:

1. Used a Script component to capture the 2 variables as ReadOnly inputs but that didn't work as the variables cannot be accessed inside the script apparently
2. Used a lookup transform but I cant get it to compare variables

Any ideas?

Comment: By fail, do you mean that the destination (CSV/table) should not be populated if the row counts are not equal? Is that why you are using the Script Component? If not, as bilinkc has suggested below, that's the way to go

Answer (score 0):

To restate, you have two Variables of type integer and you need to figure out how to make the SSIS package fail if they are not equal. You capture row counts from the Data Flow. After the Data Flow completes, you could add a Script Task (not Script Component) to the Control Flow and pass in @[User::DbRowCount] and @[User::DfRowCount]

You'd then have something in your script like

```
int dbRowCount = (int) this.Dts.Variables["DbRowCount"].Value;
int dfRowCount = (int) this.Dts.Variables["DfRowCount"].Value;
if (dbRowCount != dfRowCount)
{
    this.Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Invalid row counts", "error", string.Empty, 0);
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```